# Configuring wcf soap 1.2 service

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap

I am working on implementation of service that should accept SOAP 1.2 request with with HTNG 2.1 header, WS-Addressing (to communicate message IDs between systems and address destinations) and WS-Security (user authentication only). 
I have completed the whole business logic of processing payload message and generating proper response but I have a real trouble configuring my service to predefined request.
Here it is:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap2:Header xmlns:soap2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
  xmlns:htng="http://htng.org/1.3/Header/"
  xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
  xmlns:wss="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:htnga="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2007/02/AsyncHeaders"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsa:Action>http://MyHost/MyService_SubmitRequest</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <htnga:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>HTTPS://ResponseHost/Response.SVC</wsa:Address>
    </htnga:ReplyTo>
    <wss:Security mustUnderstand="1">
      <wss:UsernameToken>
        <wss:Username>string</wss:Username>
        <wss:Password>string</wss:Password>
      </wss:UsernameToken>
    </wss:Security>
    <wsa:MessageID>df559145-78a4-4c85-a264-bf99bbf8df9e</wsa:MessageID>
    <htnga:CorrelationID>df559145-78a4-4c85-a264-bf99bbf8df9e</htnga:CorrelationID>
    <wsa:To>https://pms.url</wsa:To>
  </soap2:Header>
  <Body>
    <!-- Payload -->
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I want configuration in config file, not in code and I have tried all configuration options I could find in various posts without any success. 
I am aware that I am probably missing some basics about WCF that I can't spot right now so at least a point in right direction will help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the MesaageID/ReplyTo header could be added in the SOAP header by setting up the message version.
[How to add MessageID in the soap headers of WCF request and response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262296/how-to-add-messageid-in-the-soap-headers-of-wcf-request-and-response)
And UsernameToken could be added by authenticating the client with username/password pattern.

```
   <customBinding>
       <binding name="mybinding">
         <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10">
         </textMessageEncoding>
         <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false" >
         </security>
         <httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
       </binding>
     </customBinding>
```

Result.
[image]
[Correct way communicate WSSE Usernametoken for SOAP webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836685/correct-way-communicate-wsse-usernametoken-for-soap-webservice)
I don’t know how to add `HGNGA:CorrelationID` header to the SOAP header, It might relate to the WCF tracing.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you Abraham.. This is a start.